# Как сделать кнопку показать/скрыть ?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Доброго времени друзья! Есть 2 дива, по клику на один, должен скрываться и показываться второй и кнопка должна менять название  на показать и скрыть! Мой скрипт работает только раз :

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //$('#forPhotosG').hide();
            var vis = $('#forPhotosG').is(":visible");
            if(vis == false){
                $('.head_b').text('Показать фото Галерею');
            vis = true;
            }
            $('#butShowHide').click(function(){
                $('.head_b').text('Скрыть фото Галерею');
                vis == false;
                $('#forPhotosG').slideToggle("slow");
                return false;
            });
        });
```

После 2х нажатий остается Скрыть фотогалерею( в чем моя ошибка растолкуйте пожалуйста)

```
<div id='butShowHide' style='width:100%;height:50px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;cursor:pointer'>
<b class="head_b">Показать</b>
</div>

<div id='forPhotosG' style='display:none'></div>
```

Попробовал сделать так: 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //$('#forPhotosG').hide();

```
            function intervalcheg(){
            var vis = $('#forPhotosG').is(":visible");
            if(vis == false){
                $('.head_b').text('Показать фото Галерею');
            }
            }
            $('#butShowHide').click(function(){
                $('.head_b').text('Скрыть фото Галерею');
                $('#forPhotosG').slideToggle("slow");
                return false;
            });
            intervalcheg();
            setInterval(intervalcheg,3000);
        });
```

Та же песня(

Comment: первая часть вашего кода выполняется только один раз.

Comment: А нет последний Вариант заработал))) только через секунды 2 меняется обратно!

Comment: что-то вы намудрили.... очень сильно

Comment: сделай просто 2 CSS класса - один для видимого дива, другой для скрытого и меняй их по событию - итого будет пару строк

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот же - все просто.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var $forPhotosG = $('#forPhotosG'),
         $head_b = $('.head_b');
     $('#butShowHide').click(function () {
         $forPhotosG.finish();
         var vis = $forPhotosG.is(":visible"),
             text = vis ? 'Показать фото Галерею' : 'Скрыть фото Галерею';
         $head_b.text(text);
         $forPhotosG.slideToggle("slow");
         return false;
     });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tf5eF/1/

Answer (score 0):

Немного проще:

Вариант 1, - пежонский:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
        $(e.target).text($('#somediv').toggle().is(':visible') ? 'Скрыть' : 'Показать');
    });
```

Вариант 2, - чтоб другие не ругались:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function (e) {
    var btnLabel = $('#somediv')
        .toggle()
        .is(':visible')
        ? 'Скрыть' : 'Показать';
    $(e.target).text(btnLabel);
});
```

Comment: рассказать почему с анимацией работать не будет ?

Comment: Да, буду очень признателен. Только раскройте суть проблемы. что вы имеете ввиду  под анимацией.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду что то типа вмеcто toggle необходимо будет slideUp какой нибудь, то да, придется менять код. Но ответ был по задаче, показать/скрыть. В любом случае чтобы сохранить лаконичность, а заодно и повысить скил, можно будет написать кастомную jquery функцию   toggleAnimate или что то вроде того :)))

Comment: там задача с конкретным кодом а не абстрактным. показать скрыть можно вообще с css.